# Extjs 4.1 drag and drop treeview node into grid to dynamically add column

Tags: drag-and-drop, extjs4.1

I have a treeview that contains available column headers as tree nodes. I also have a grid. What I need to do is drag one of the tree nodes into the column header section of the grid to dynamically add a new column. Both my treeview and grid are configured and rendered correctly.

My treeview is configured as follows:

```
    var tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            dragGroup: 'myDDGroup'
        }
    ...
```

My grid is configured as follows:

```
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dropGroup: 'myDDGroup'
        }
    ...
```

I would say this worked perfectly if what I wanted to do was drag a tree node into the grid to add a new row. Instead, as I mentioned, what I want to do is drag a node into the column header section to add a new column (not a row).

I see in ExtJS source (ViewDropZone.js) the implementation for handling the OnNodeDrop event and looks like it's working as designed. I suppose I could write my own OnNodeDrop event handler to accomplish the behavior I need. Before I went down that path, I wanted to see if someone either has already implemented a similar solution or know of an alternative/better solution.